# Computation of adjoint functors (sheafification)

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

In a (complete) category, limits can be "computed" assuming one knows how to compute products and equalisers.

I have seen it mentioned that adjoint functors can be found using certain limits/colimits. Is this construction related to the adjoint functor theorem, or is that less constructive?

I am looking for an **accessible** reference on this topic, with the very concrete goal in mind of computing a left adjoint of $\mathrm{PSh}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathrm{Sh}(\mathcal{C})$, that is sheafifcation.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can compute adjoints in terms of limits/colimits. In fact that is what the adjoint functor theorem says.

Comment: Yes, this is the adjoint functor theorem. Go to Mac Lane for reference.

Comment: Ah, ok, so I really just need to learn the adjoint functor theorem, or is there more to it? I found this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844131/adjoint-functor-theorem/844384#844384 which seemed to suggest that the resulting construction is not very good for computation

Comment: Also, I realised my question wasn't concrete enough, so I edited it!

Comment: Yes, also this is correct. The theorem is constructive, but the construction is not helpful.

Comment: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sheafification

Comment: @JakobWerner, yeah, I asked this question basically because that article is a bit too high tech for me that this stage

Comment: Look up the Grothendieck plus construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three ways of constructing the left adjoint of $\mathbf{Sh}(\mathcal{C}, J) \hookrightarrow \mathbf{Psh}(\mathcal{C})$ using limits or colimits:

1. Use the accessible (pun intended) adjoint functor theorem. (See Chapter 1 of *Locally presentable and accessible categories* or Chapter 5 of *Handbook of categorical algebra, volume 2*.)
2. Use a small object argument. (See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/160180/11640) for details.)
3. Use Grothendieck's plus construction twice. (See [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/plus+construction+on+presheaves) or Chapter III of *Sheaves in geometry and logic*.)

Of the three constructions, only the third one explains why sheafification preserves finite limits. The idea is very simple; indeed, so simple that one is at first surprised that it doesn't work, and then surprised again that it works after just one repetition.

Let $F$ be a presheaf on $\mathcal{C}$. Then for any sieve $\mathfrak{U}$ on a fixed object $C$ in $\mathcal{C}$, one can form the set $F (\mathfrak{U})$ of matching families of sections over $\mathfrak{U}$. Evidently, if $\mathfrak{U} \subseteq \mathfrak{V}$, then we have a map $F (\mathfrak{U}) \to F (\mathfrak{V})$, and in fact we get a diagram of sets indexed by the opposite of the poset of sieves on $C$. If $J$ is a Grothendieck topology, then the subposet $J (C)$ of $J$-covering sieves on $C$ is a filter, and $F^+ (C)$ is defined to be the filtered colimit $\varinjlim_{\mathfrak{U} : J (C)^\mathrm{op}} F (\mathfrak{U})$. With a bit more work we find that $F^+$ is a presheaf on $\mathcal{C}$.

Thus, $F^+$ is the presheaf of equivalence classes of matching families of sections of $F$. As it turns out, $F^+$ is in general only a separated presheaf and not a sheaf; but if $F$ is already separated then $F^+$ is a sheaf. Thus $F^{++}$ is always a sheaf. One can then show that the evident morphism $F \to F^{++}$ exhibits $F^{++}$ as the sheafification of $F$.