# Proof that free groups exist without the theory of finite words

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I am interested in developing a formal proof that free groups exist, i.e. for any set $S$ there is a group $G\supseteq S$ such that for any group $H$ and any function $f:S\to H$ there is a homomorphism $\sigma\supseteq f$ from $G$ to $H$. (I don't think it is necessary for $\sigma$ to be unique for the existence proof.) Is there any way to prove this other than the explicit construction: (I hope I can give you a flavor of why this would be really annoying to do formally.)

> - Let $\Sigma=2\times S=\{\langle 0,x\rangle, \langle 1,x\rangle:x\in S\}$.
> - Let $X=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\Sigma^n$.
> - Define the concatenation operation $\sqcup:X\times X\to X$ by $$\def\dom{\operatorname{dom}}
>   x\sqcup y=x\cup\{\langle n+\dom x+1,z\rangle:\langle n,z\rangle\in y\}.$$
> - Define ${}^{-1}:\Sigma\to\Sigma$ such that $\langle 0,x\rangle^{-1}=\langle 1,x\rangle$ and $\langle 1,x\rangle^{-1}=\langle 0,x\rangle$.
> - Define the equivalence $\sim$ as the reflexive/symmetric/transitive closure of $$\{\langle x,y\rangle:\exists n\in \Sigma, \exists z,w\in X\,(x=z\sqcup w\land y=z\sqcup\{\langle 0,n\rangle, \langle 1,n^{-1}\rangle\}\sqcup w) \}.$$
> - Define $G=(X,\sqcup)/\sim$. Then $G$ is a group, where $S$ is embedded as $x\mapsto[\{\langle 0,\langle 0,x\rangle\rangle\}]_\sim$.

What I am looking for are "slick" proofs that avoid all the dirty details here to show that there exists a group satisfying the categorical property of a free group without this concatenation/reduction stuff.

Comment: If you know a little bit category theory, you can use Freyd's existence theorem for adjoint functors. Have a look at Martin Brandenburg's Answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844131/adjoint-functor-theorem

Comment: I think there is a way of defining free groups using inverse limits. So for the free group on $X$, the objects would be something like pairs $(G,\phi_G)$ with $\phi_G:X \to G$, and homomorphisms between objects that commuted with the $\phi_G$, but I may be misremembering!

Comment: Google "van der Waerden's Trick" or read it directly in, for example, Rotman's book. It is very nice and uses permutations groups

Comment: @DerekHolt you are propably referring to the proof one can find in Lang's Algebra which is basically a proof of Freyd's theorem in elementary terms in this special case.

Comment: @Timbuc I have Rotman's book (Advanced Modern Algebra), but I could not find anything relevant under "van der Waerden" or "trick". If there is a proof from permutation groups that would be great, but I'm having trouble finding the reference.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Sorry about that: I meant Joseph Rotman's "Introduction to the Theory of Groups", chapter 11, theorem 11.1, page 344 of 4th edition.

Comment: @Timbuc Ah, I'm a little disappointed since it still seems to need the theory of words and reduced words in order to prove. The only thing it seems to save is proof of associativity, and so is barely better than the proof outline I made in the OP, which reduces this to associativity of $\sqcup$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro As for "existence" I think that, or something like that, will be pretty similar in this or that. If you're willing to contentate with a more abstract, way more "ethereal" approach in, as mentioned in other comments, Lang's Algebra, Chapter 1, $\;\S 12\;$ , with commutative diagrams and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can do some category theory, I'm not a big fan of it since it seems to bury any concept in several layers of definition for little gain. Thus I'm going to restate [Martin Brandenburg's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/844384/50776) to a variation on this question in "elementary" terms, following the suggestions of Jakob Werner and Derek Holt on this page.

Let $\Sigma=2\times S$, $X=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\Sigma^n$. Now this looks similar to the setup in the OP, but we aren't going to use it to define any algebra of words; this is purely needed for its cardinality. If $G$ is a group and $S$ generates $G$, then the function $\sigma:X\to G$ defined by $\sigma(x)=\tau(x_1)\tau(x_2)\dots\tau(x_n)$ where $\tau:\Sigma\to G$ sets $\tau(0,x)=x,\tau(1,x)=x^{-1}$ must be a surjection onto $G$. Thus $|G|\le|X|$ (looks like some AC snuck in, any suggestions for how to eliminate this?).

Now let $\cal G$ be the set of all pairs $(G,\phi_G)$ such that $G$ is a group whose base set is a subset of $X$, and $\phi_G$ is an injection from $S$ to $G$ that generates $G$ (here is where we use boundedness of $X$ to show that $\cal G$ is a set), and define $P=\prod_{(G,\phi_G)\in\cal G}G$ as a group with the operation of pointwise group operation. $S$ is embedded into $P$ as $x\in S\mapsto((G,\phi_G)\in{\cal G}\mapsto\phi_G(x))$, and let $F$ be the subgroup of $P$ generated by $S$ under this map.

The claim is that $F$ is freely generated by $S$. Given a group $H$ and a function $f:S\to H$, let $T$ be the subgroup of $H$ generated by $f(S)$. Then $|T|\le|X|$, so let $i$ be an injection from $T$ to $X$. We have $i(T)\subseteq X$, and with the group operation inherited from $H$, $i(T)$ is a group, so $(i(T),i\circ f)\in\cal G$, and we can define $\sigma:P\to H$ as $\sigma(x)=i^{-1}(x(i(T),i\circ f))$; this is a homomorphism, and its restriction to $F$ is unique.

Believe it or not this kind of argumentation is much easier to formalize and does not require too much details about groups (since it's ultimately a category theory proof), although one needs to know that the "generation" operation does not make a set *too* much bigger, hence the "ugly stuff" in the second paragraph.