# Solution set condition and the forgetful functor $U:\textbf{Gr}\rightarrow\textbf{Set}$

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Let $U:\textbf{Gr}\rightarrow\textbf{Set}$ be the forgetful functor from the category of groups to the category of sets.

Let $X\in\textbf{Set}$. I want to construct the solution set $S_X\subset\text{Ob}(\textbf{Gr})$ associated to $X$. I propose the following correspondence:
$$S_X:=\left\{G\in\textbf{Gr}\ |\ (\exists i)(X\xrightarrow{i} U(G)\land\text{"$i(X)$ generates $G$"})\right\}.$$
The trouble is that I am not sure how to prove that the class $S_X$ is a set. In his answer to the question [Adjoint Functor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844131/adjoint-functor-theorem), Martin says,

> The class of these groups is essentially small, since $U(G)$ admits a
> surjection from $\coprod_n(X\times\mathbf{N})^n$.

He uses the same argument in his answer to the question [Existence proof of the tensor product using the Adjoint functor theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614461/existence-proof-of-the-tensor-product-using-the-adjoint-functor-theorem) to conclude once more that the solution class is a set; here, he says

> Then $\#|A'|\leq\aleph_0\cdot\#|M|\cdot\#|N|$. Hence, up to
> isomorphism, there is only a set of such $A's.$

What sort of an argument is this? I am not clear about why showing that $|U(G)|\leq|\coprod_n(X\times\mathbf{N})^n|$, for each $G\in S_X$, allows us to conclude that $S_X$ is a set. Can someone please flesh this out for me?

Comment: Strictly speaking $S_X$ is not a set, for $X = \{1\}$ (with $1 ∈ ℤ$), $ℤ ∈ S_X$, but for all sets $T$ with $T \notin ℤ$, you can replace $0$ in $ℤ$ by $T$ to get a new set $ℤ_T$ and update the group structure accordingly to have $T$ act as the new neutral element and $ℤ_T ∈ S_X$ since $1 ∈ ℤ_T$. Just doing this with the class of all singletons $T$ shows that $S_X$ is way too big.

Comment: @k.stm So, does that mean that the proposed set is not the right candidate for the solution set $S_X$?

Comment: I dunno, Martin speaks of a “essentially small class” here, which is a notion with which I’m not familiar. Maybe he meant an *essentially small category* of some sort and this notion suffices here? Let’s wait and see – someone will come along and shed some light onto this.

Comment: It suffices to have at least one representative of each isomorphism class – and by Scott's trick we can construct a set that has at least one representative of each isomorphism class. The point is that the cardinality of a group generated by a set $X$ is bounded above by the greater of $\aleph_0$ or the cardinality of $X$ itself – so you don't even need Scott's trick: just consider groups whose underlying set is a subset of $X \amalg \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Do you mean to say that I can take $S_X:=\{G\subset(X\coprod\mathbf{N})\ |\ (\exists *)(\exists f)((G,*)\in\textbf{Gr}\land f: X\rightarrow G)\}$?

Comment: Yes. Though you have to convince yourself that this is really a solution _set_.

Comment: An "essentially small class" would mean that the class is a small set, up to isomorphism. That is, the class has only a set of isomorphism classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just interested in finding some solution set, then there is an easier answer. Arguably this is cheating though, because it uses the description of the left adjoint $F$ of the forgetful functor $U: \mathbf{Gr} \to \mathbf{Set}$.

That being said, let's fix some set $X$. Then I claim that $\{F(X)\}$, where $F$ is the free group on $X$, is a solution set. Indeed, let $f: X \to U(G)$ be any function of sets. Then because $F(X)$ is the free group on $X$ we can extend $f$ to a group homomorphism $\bar{f}: F(X) \to G$ such that $\bar{f} i = f$, where $i: X \to F(X)$ is the obvious injection of the generators.

---

As I said, this is cheating because it uses a description of the left adjoint of $U$. Indeed, the free group functor $F: \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Gr}$ is the left adjoint of $U$. So the above is just a specific instance of the following fact.

> Let $L: \mathcal{C} \rightleftarrows \mathcal{D}: R$ and let $C$ be an object in $\mathcal{C}$. Then $\{ L(C) \}$ is a solution set for $R$, associated to $C$.

Proving this would be a nice exercise. Hint: use the unit $\eta_C: C \to RL(C)$.

---

The class $S_X$ you proposed is of course going to capture the free group as well, so it will definitely contain enough. As already mentioned in the comments, $S_X$ is technically a proper class. However, this is no issue, because it will be essentially small. That means that there is a set $S_X'$ such that for every group $G \in S_X$ there is $G' \in S_X'$ with $G' \cong G$. So technically $S_X'$ would be our solution set, but we might as well work with $S_X$ and suppress the isomorphisms in our notation (so this is purely for convenience).

To prove that this class is essentially small, you quote another answer where they give a cardinality argument. Basically what they say is that there is some cardinal $\kappa$ such that for all $G \in S_X$ we have $|U(G)| \leq \kappa$. If we fix a set $Y$ then there is only a set of group structures on $Y$. So for every cardinal $\lambda \leq \kappa$ there is, up to isomorphism, only a set of group structures where the underlying set has cardinality $\lambda$. Hence there is, up to isomorphism, only a set of groups where the underlying set has cardinality $\leq \kappa$.

In both answers you quoted it is explained how this cardinality bound is found (although I think in the first one it should be $\mathbb{Z}$ in place of $\mathbb{N}$, but this is of no real consequence).